# Hiranyakashipu told everyone to worship himself as God, was he correct according to advaita?

Tags: advaita

Main tenets of Advaita is to realize that you are God, But Hiranyakashipu did the same, Was he correct according to Advaita? He had acquired Astama siddhi  because of which he is able to travel to vaikuntha, but not able to see Vishnu, which no Asura or other godly being done including Prahalad, Arjuna.

Comment: Hirayakashyipu feels he is Brahman out of ego. But Advaita's notion is we should experience we are Brahman, like in state of Jivanmukta, without realization Sadhaka can only know intellectually he is Brahman but can't really feel himself as God, and for that Sadhaka world is real like other beings.  So, first Vedas say "tat Tvam Asi" and then we experience after realization "Aham Brahmasmi". He couldn't see Vishnu (Vishnum = who is spread everywhere) as he didn't experience Vishnu (permeating Brahman everywhere).

Comment: First step to realize without ego that im God than you are verily that God who is invincible (not slayed, no death). is it not your ego is emboldened to that extent that you are invincible and defy death.. than you can say that im God or I will be equal to him God.. But if you destroy the eGO then you are nothing.. that is what you are able to identify yourself as you. personally there is only one way that one can call oneself as God is emboldened EGO or he thinks others are just nothing all or maya @TheDestroyer

Comment: Regarding "tat Tvam Asi" this is one word taken out of uddkala and sveta ketu conversion and blown out of context. First any word that is said can be fully understood only when you know that context what, when, where, how and why is said, in management 5 why principle is there. to understand tat tvam asi, you need to get the answer 5 why? @TheDestroyer

Comment: aham Brahma asmi, if you are purely Vedic or vaidika you know that most of words in vedas are abbreviation. like "OM" kara, for person of less intellect its just one letter, but if you split its 3 letter, shankara says its 6 letter, but Bhogar said its 8 letter, M@Thedestroyer

Comment: adhvacharya said its 8 letter.. so for lay person "OM" one. only one. like that this aham (A-z) aa - ha iti is aham its first and last letter of Sanskrit alphabet. According Madhva its abbreviation of Gods name, aham is ham, asmi, sa so so ham asmi  is converter ham asmi and aa is added so aham asmi, that is brahman, aham brahma asmi is brahman, hamsa is brahma s name. @Thedestroyer

Comment: I will give you the standard reply by advaitins - advaitins dont think they are God/Ishwara/Vishnu/saguna brahman. Advaitins think they are nirguna brahman.

Comment: @LazyLubber Does this question need an answer really? Was Hiranyakasipu a seeker at all?

Comment: @PrasannaR Hope you know that your question is an insult to AdvaitavAda. Please dont try to denigrate others' doctrines. Sri Madhva has also been referred to as an incarnation of VatApi! These just ruin us.

Comment: @Pratimaputra If the question was asked with a genuine spirit of enquiry, it deserves an answer.

Comment: So there are 2 Brahman one suguna and other is nirguna this itself contradicts Advita @lazylubber

Comment: @Prasanna Saguna brahman is nirguna brahman with upadhis. The upadhis are unreal.

Comment: When the discussion is about concept why u cast aspersions on Guru I don't want to argue on this aspersions @pratimaputra

Comment: @PrasannaR do you conceptually find Hiranya an Advaitin?

Comment: So according to the upadhi u have contradicted your own statement @lazylubber

Comment: How so? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The one is enlightened who sees god everywhere even in ownself without duality. Hiranyakashipu and his ancestors where no common one's.He knew more than what we think to know.But he's ego was against he's sprituality.